# Why is the bottom content truncated in AppBarLayout?

Tags: android, fragment, bottomnavigationview

I am using `BottomNavigationView` and `AppBarLayout`.
But the content at the bottom of the `AppBarLayout` is cut off as in the picture.
How do I make everything visible? (I can't move the graph upwards because there is something to add at the top of the graph.)

[image]

Below is the XML code of the screen in the picture: (Fragment)

```
    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_weight="1">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart
        android:id="@+id/lineChart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp">

    </com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.LineChart>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="보이니?"
        android:textSize="23sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Below is the `AppbarLayout` XML code that the fragment contains.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:color/background_light"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/design_default_color_primary_dark"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/design_default_color_primary" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"></FrameLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Below is the `BottomNavigationView` XML code.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".HomeDefault">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigationView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"></FrameLayout>

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/frameLayout"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_navigation_color"
    app:menu="@menu/menubar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I don't see bottomnavigationview in the layout

Comment: sorry, i updated the bottomnavigationview xml code